# Obter data-ref de diferentes botões

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

Criei um sistema em que exibe os dados de uma tabela `mysql`por meio do plugin `datable`. Um dos dados exbidos é um modal. O codigo javascript  pega o `data-ref`, que contem o `id`. Este `id` vai ser usado em querys `mysql` futuras.

**A Duvida**: quando são geradas mais de uma linha, o ajax sempre retorna o id da primeira linha, e não o id referente a linha clica. Quero saber como retornar o `id` (que esta em um atributo `data-ref`) da linha especifica.

Esse é codigo javascript que obtem o "id" e dispara o ajax:

```
        $('#verpedido').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        let id_pedido = $("#detalha").attr('data-ref');
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://notasfiscais-ipc.stackstaging.com/edita.php',
        data: {id: id_pedido},
        type: 'POST',

        success: function(response){

        $('#teste').empty();
        $('#teste').html(response);
        }
        });
        });
```

Esse é o HTML da table:

```
            <td class="sorting_1">34592</td><td>005_17</td><td>CLIENTE 01</td><td>2017-04-12</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><a href="#ver_pedido" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verpedido" data-ref="34592" id="detalha" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> </td></tr>
            <tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">35194</td><td>2689</td><td>CLIENTE 02</td><td>2017-05-16</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><a href="#ver_pedido" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verpedido" data-ref="35194" id="detalha" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> </td></tr>
        </tbody>`
```

Comment: Tem q criar um id diferente para cada linha. Seu código já jaz isso?

Comment: Formata melhor esse código aí...

Answer (score 0):

Precisamos analisar que #detalha é um id único. O que podemos fazer é da seguinte forma:

```
$('#verpedido').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    let id_pedido = $(".detalha").attr('data-ref');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://notasfiscais-ipc.stackstaging.com/edita.php',
            data: {id: id_pedido},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                $('#teste').empty();
                $('#teste').html(response);
            }
        });
});




<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verpedido" data-ref="34592" class="btn btn-primary detalha"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verpedido" data-ref="34593" class="btn btn-primary detalha"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Sendo assim, aplicando a classe, conseguirá obter o resultado esperado.
Note que removi o id="detalha" e apliquei o detalha como classe.

Answer (score 0):

1º voce não pode (pelo menos não deve) ter elementos com o mesmo id.

2º Voce tem que manipular o `button` ou `link`que foi clicado e depois chamar o modal. Uma forma de fazer seria assim:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
    let id_pedido = $(this).attr('data-ref');

    // chamar o modal dentro do click

    alert(id_pedido);

    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://notasfiscais-ipc.stackstaging.com/edita.php',
       data: {id: id_pedido},
       type: 'POST',

       success: function(response){
          $('#teste').empty();
          $('#teste').html(response);
       }
    });
 });
```